# JavaScript plugin - cannot read property 'window' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write vanilla JavaScript plugin but getting following error:

```
cannot read property 'window' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
    define([], factory(root));
  } else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
    module.exports = factory(root);
  } else {
    root.myPlugin = factory(root);
  }
})(typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : this.window || this.global, function (root) {
  'use strict';
...
```

Comment: [See this section in the `this` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get real fancy, you could change your long line to something like

```
(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : 
        typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self :
        typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : {}, function (root) {
    // code
});
```

But it would always be better for you to learn about scope like Patrick suggested.